# Waiting on the results of GetGeopositionAsync()

Tags: c#, .net, geolocation, task-parallel-library, async-await

I'm developing a WinPhone 8 App. 
On this App there is a Button 'Send SMS'. 
When the user clicks on this button two things should happen:

1. (Method A) Get the geo-coordinate of the current Location (using Geolocator and GetGeopositionAsync).
2. (Method B) Compose and send an SMS with the geo-coordinate as part of the body.

The Problem: GetGeopositionAsync is an asynchronous method. Before the coordinate is detected (which takes a few seconds) the SMS is sent (of course with no coordinates).

How can I tell Method 2 to wait until the coordinates are available?

OK, here is my code:

When the user presses the button, the coordinates are determined by the first method and the second method sends the SMS which includes the coordinates in its body:

```
private void btnSendSms_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    GetCurrentCoordinate();  // Method 1
    // -> Gets the coordinates

    SendSms();               // Method 2
    // Sends the coordinates within the body text
}
```

The first method GetCurrentCoordinate() looks as follows:

```
        ...
private GeoCoordinate MyCoordinate = null;
private ReverseGeocodeQuery MyReverseGeocodeQuery = null;
private double _accuracy = 0.0;
        ...

private async void GetCurrentCoordinate()
{
    Geolocator geolocator = new Geolocator();
    geolocator.DesiredAccuracy = PositionAccuracy.High;

    try
    {
        Geoposition currentPosition = await geolocator.GetGeopositionAsync(
            TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1), 
            TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
        lblLatitude.Text = currentPosition.Coordinate.Latitude.ToString("0.000");
        lblLongitude.Text = currentPosition.Coordinate.Longitude.ToString("0.000");
        _accuracy = currentPosition.Coordinate.Accuracy;
        MyCoordinate = new GeoCoordinate(
            currentPosition.Coordinate.Latitude, 
            currentPosition.Coordinate.Longitude);
        if (MyReverseGeocodeQuery == null || !MyReverseGeocodeQuery.IsBusy)
        {
            MyReverseGeocodeQuery = new ReverseGeocodeQuery();
            MyReverseGeocodeQuery.GeoCoordinate = new GeoCoordinate(
                MyCoordinate.Latitude, 
                MyCoordinate.Longitude);
            MyReverseGeocodeQuery.QueryCompleted += ReverseGeocodeQuery_QueryCompleted;
            MyReverseGeocodeQuery.QueryAsync();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception)
    { // Do something }
}

private void ReverseGeocodeQuery_QueryCompleted(object sender, 
                                                QueryCompletedEventArgs<IList<MapLocation>> e)
{
    if (e.Error == null)
    {
        if (e.Result.Count > 0)
        {
            MapAddress address = e.Result[0].Information.Address;
            lblCurrAddress.Text = address.Street + " " + address.HouseNumber + ",\r" +
                address.PostalCode + " " + address.City + ",\r" +
                address.Country + " (" + address.CountryCode + ")";

            }
        }
    }
}
```

And the Methode 'SendSms()':

```
private void SendSms()
{
    SmsComposeTask smsComposeTask = new SmsComposeTask();
    smsComposeTask.To = "0123456";
    smsComposeTask.Body = "Current position: \rLat = " + lblLatitude.Text + 
        ", Long = " + lblLongitude.Text +
        "\r" + lblCurrAddress.Text;
    // -> The TextBoxes are still empty!
    smsComposeTask.Show();
}
```

**The problem is, that all these TextBoxes (lblLatitude, lblLongitude, lblCurrAddress) are still empty when the method SendSms() sets the SmsComposeTask object.**

I have to ensure that the TextBoxes are already set BEFORE the method SendSms() starts.

Comment: You should show some attempt to solve it by yourself using code

Answer (score 3):

You should almost **never** mark a method `async void` unless it's a UI event handler. You're calling an asynchronous method without waiting for it to end. You are basically calling those 2 methods in parallel, so it's clear why the coordinates aren't available.

You need to make `GetCurrentCoordinate` return an awaitable task and await it, like this:

```
private async Task GetCurrentCoordinateAsync()
{
    //....
}

private async void btnSendSms_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    await GetCurrentCoordinateAsync();
    // You'll get here only after the first method finished asynchronously.
    SendSms();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is one of the primary reasons you should avoid `async void`. `void` is a very unnatural return type for `async` methods.

First, make your `GetCurrentCoordinate` an `async Task` method instead of `async void`. Then, you can change your click handler to look like this:

```
private async void btnSendSms_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  await GetCurrentCoordinate();
  SendSms();
}
```

Your click handler is `async void` only because event handlers *have* to return `void`. But you should really strive to avoid `async void` in all other code.

Answer (score 0):

There two things you're doing wrong here:

1. Using void returning `async` methods when you need to await on them. This is bad because you can't await on execution of these methods and should only be used when you can't make the method return `Task` or `Task<T>`. That's why you're not seeing anything on the text boxes when `SendSms`is called.
2. Mixing UI and non-UI code. You should transfer data between UI and non-UI code to avoid tight coupling between code with different responsibilities. IT also makes it easy to read and debug the code.

`ReverseGeocodeQuery` does not have an awaitable async API but [you can easily make your own](http://developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/Bringing_async/await_to_the_Contacts_service):

```
private async Task<IList<MapLocation>> ReverseGeocodeQueryAsync(GeoCoordinate geoCoordinate)
{
    var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<IList<MapLocation>>();

    EventHandler<QueryCompletedEventArgs<IList<MapLocation>>> handler =
        (s, e) =>
        {
            if (e.Cacelled)
            {
                tcs.TrySetCancelled();
            }
            else if (e.Error != null)
            {
                tcs.TrySetException(e.Error);
            }
            else
            {
                tcs.TrySetResult(e.Result);
            }
        };

    var query = new ReverseGeocodeQuery{ GeoCoordinate = geoCoordinate };
    try
    {
        query.QueryCompleted += handler;
        query.QueryAsync();

        return await tcs.Task;
    }
    finally
    {
        query.QueryCompleted -= handler;
    }
}
```

This way you'll get full cancellation and error support.

Now let's make the retrieval of the geo coordinate information all in one chunk:

```
private async Task<Tuple<Geocoordinate, MapLocation>> GetCurrentCoordinateAsync()
{
    try
    {
        var geolocator = new Geolocator
            {
                DesiredAccuracy = PositionAccuracy.High
            };

        var currentPosition = await geolocator.GetGeopositionAsync(
            TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1), 
            TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10))
            .ConfigureAwait(continueOnCapturedContext: false);

        var currentCoordinate = currentPosition.Coordinate;

        var mapLocation = await this.ReverseGeocodeQueryAsync(
            new GeoCoordinate(
                currentCoordinate.Latitude, 
                currentCoordinate.Longitude));

        return Tuple.Create(
            currentCoordinate,
            mapLocation.FirstOrDefault());
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        // Do something...
        return Tuple.Create(null, null);
    }
}
```

Now the button eventnt handler becomes much more readable:

```
private void btnSendSms_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var info = await GetCurrentCoordinate();

    if (info.Item1 != nuil)
    {
        lblLatitude.Text = info.Item1.Latitude.ToString("0.000");
        lblLongitude.Text = info.Item1.Longitude.ToString("0.000");
    }

    if (info.Item2 != null)
    {
        var address = info.Item2.Information.Address;

        lblCurrAddress.Text = string.Format(
            "{0} {1},\n{2} {3},\n{4} ({5})",
             address.Street,
             address.HouseNumber,
             address.PostalCode,
             address.City,
             address.Country,
             address.CountryCode);
    }

    SendSms(info.Item1, info.Item2);
}
```

Does this make sense?